# Create Index Array in jQuery

Tags: jquery

here's my code.

```
    jQuery('#delete_item').click(function(){
        var arr = array();
        jQuery('.man_id:checked').each(function (){
            var value = jQuery(this).val();
            arr += value;
        });
        alert(arr);

    });
```

what I want is to store all the value in the array.. is it possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Mistake 1:** Actually you declare `array()` is wrong there two methods to declare array in javascript

```
1) var arr = new Array();

2) var arr = [];
```

**Mistake 2:** You have concanate the array but actually we have use push() method to insert array in javascript. Pushing array with two methods I given below

```
 1) arr.push(value);
 2) arr[index] = value;
```

your code be

```
jQuery('#delete_item').click(function(){
        var arr = [];
        jQuery('.man_id:checked').each(function (){
            var value = jQuery(this).val();
            arr.push(value);
        });
        alert(arr);

    });
```

Comment: ty sir.. you are a great help. =)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery.map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) to get the array. Using `this.value` will be more efficient then use `jQuery(this).val()`;

```
jQuery('#delete_item').click(function(){
    var arr = jQuery('.man_id:checked').map(function(){
        return this.value;
    }).get();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [.map()](https://api.jquery.com/map)

```
jQuery('#delete_item').click(function () {
    var arr = jQuery('.man_id:checked').map(function () {
        return this.value
    }).get();
    alert(arr);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use **[map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/)** in jquery .Translate all items in an array

```
  var arr = $('.man_id:checked').map(function (){
             return this.value;
        }).get();
        alert(arr);
```

Comment: @downvoter Please put your comment for your downvote, without comment  it would't change anything here

Comment: @NorlihazmeyGhazali ennada enna ?

Comment: @Bala  - You have to improve your communication skill da .